# How to use Jobs resource in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

How do I use the ['Job' resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs) within the Google Apps Script?

I understand that YouTube Reporting API has to be enabled, but what object can it be called from?

I am trying to access YouTube Reporting API. is this the right way to call it?
If so, my Apps Script can't identify youtubeReporting, why would that be?

```
youtubeReporting.jobs()
```

To sum up, my goal is to extract 'Content Owner Reports' bulk/query, pretty much read all the steps leading to that, except the very starting point, which is an object name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: Although this answer deals with  YouTube reporting api, the flow should be the same for all Google apis, where advanced Google service wrapper isn't provided.**

AFAICT, YouTube reporting API isn't directly available as a advanced Google service. You may be able to use [YouTubeanalytics api, which is provided as a advanced Google service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics). To  access reporting api, You need to [directly connect to the api through HTTP calls](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) and [urlfetch](/questions/tagged/urlfetch).

#### Required reading:

- [Advanced or HTTP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#advanced_services_or_http)
- [ScriptApp#getOauthToken](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken())
- [YouTube reporting rest](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs)
- [UrlFetchApp#fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app.html#fetch(String,Object))
- [Editing manifest#Setting explicit scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes)
- [Switch to standard GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- [API Library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library)

#### Solution:

- It is possible to access YouTube reporting api from Google apps script  using `UrlFetchApp`
- Full OAuth flow can be bypassed using oauth token provided by `ScriptApp`
- Include scopes in the appsscript.json manifest file.
- Switch to a standard GCP and enable the  YouTube reporting api for this project. Otherwise 403 will be returned.

#### Snippet:

```js
/**
 * @description A wrapper for accessing Google apis from  apps script
 * @param {string} url Google URL endpoint
 * @param {string} method HTTP method
 * @param {object} requestBody Requestbody to send
 * @param {object} pathParameters Parameters to modify in the url
 * @param {object} queryParameters Queryparameters to append to the url
 * @return {object} response
 */
function accessGoogleApiHTTP_(
  url,
  method,
  requestBody = {},
  pathParameters = {},
  queryParameters = {}
) {
  const modifiedUrl = Object.entries(pathParameters).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => acc.replace(key, value),
    url
  );
  const queryUrl = Object.entries(queryParameters).reduce(
    (acc, param) => acc + param.map(e => encodeURIComponent(e)).join('='),
    '?'
  );
  const options = {
    method,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` /*Need to set explicit scopes*/,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    modifiedUrl + queryUrl,
    options
  ).getContentText();
  console.log(res);
  return JSON.parse(res);
}
/**
 * @see https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs/create
 * @description POST https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs
 */
function createYtReportingJob() {
  const reportTypeId = 'id',
    name = 'name';
  const jsonRes = accessGoogleApiHTTP_(
    'https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs',
    'POST',
    { reportTypeId, name },
    undefined,
    { onBehalfOfContentOwner: 'contentOwnerId' }
  );
}
```

Manifest scopes:

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

In order to access the YouTube Reporting API you have to add **YouTube Analytics API** and optionally add the **YouTube Data API** as well. From this point you can create a report as in the [Apps Script: YouTube Analytics](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics#create_report) example.

Bear in mind:

- When importing the services like *YouTube Analytics API* be aware with the version.
- You can specify the amount of metrics desired.

### Reference

[Apps Script: YouTube Analytics](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube-analytics#create_report)

[YouTube Data API: Channel list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

[Analytics and Reporting APIs: Content Owner Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/content_owner_reports)